# iphone: uitextfield, multiple textfields with the same delegate?

Tags: iphone, delegates, uitextfield

there are two different textfields in my applications and i set the .delegate property of both of them to: self.
Now i implemented different methods from the uitextfielddelegate protocol but i want to be able to control the two textfields individually. For instance i want the first text field to do something different when editing begins than the second textfield... Is the only solution to this problem to set the assign a different delegate or is there a way to do this with both of the textfield having the same delegate assigned to them?
I hope my question is understandable i tried it to explain the best way that i could.....
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set a `tag` on the textfield on initialization, then check the `UITextField` object that is passed into the delegate method's `tag`, then you'll be able to make a differentiation between the two textfields:

```
#define FIELD_ONE_TAG 1
#define FIELD_TWO_TAG 2

UITextField *textFieldOne = ...
textFieldOne.tag = FIELD_ONE_TAG;
...
UITextField *textFieldTwo = ...
textFieldTwo.tag = FIELD_TWO_TAG;


- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
   if(textField.tag == FIELD_ONE_TAG) { //field one
   } else {//field two

   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
UITextField *textFieldOne=..... 

UITextField *textFieldTwo=....
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
if(textField == textFieldOne)
{ // field one code
}else{
//field two code
}
}
```

have two references of the inserted text views and u can compare them at the delegate methods. Not much needed with tags