# how to identify UITextField in a better way

Tags: ios, uitextfield, xcode-storyboard

I am using xcode8+swift3.

I have multiple `UITextField` in my controller view. Each UITextField has a outlet connection in code.

I know I can use “`tag`” to identify `UITextField`, but it seems I can only use number as tag (I tried with string value for `tag` field, my Xcode always get stuck, only number as tag works).

But I don’t want to use magic number in my code like:

```
If (textField.tag == 0) {

}
```

I am wondering, is there a better way or more descriptive way in code to identify UITextField?

Comment: That's the definition of `tag`: `@property(nonatomic) NSInteger tag;` So indeed, you can't put text. If each of them has an IBOutlet, why don't you do `if (textField == myTextFieldForSomething)` instead?

Comment: @Larme Great point; could you make that an answer? In many cases that's a better approach than mine.

Comment: @RobNapier I'm sure there should be some already asked questions about that (may be need to find it, surely about detecting with object is which in some delegate methods). They usually tends to answers with Tags or direct "==" (pointer equality) if there is a property. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747315/iphone-uitextfield-multiple-textfields-with-the-same-delegate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747889/two-uitableview-in-the-same-view etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iphone: uitextfield, multiple textfields with the same delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747315/iphone-uitextfield-multiple-textfields-with-the-same-delegate)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that one. That answer basically is "use tag." This question presumes that information and asks how to organize it in Swift (which has a very different pattern than in in ObjC).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tag is the correct tool. Just create an enum for them to track.

```
enum FieldIdentifier: Int {
    case name = 0
    case age = 1
}

if let fieldIdentifier = FieldIdentifier(rawValue: textField.tag) {
    switch fieldIdentifier {
    case .name: ...
    case .age: ...
    }
}
```

(Note that Larme's comment about using `==` is also appropriate, and if you already have outlets is better.)