# How to distinguish between two textFields in a custom cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have two textFields (storyTitle and Author) in a custom cell in a tableview and would like to edit and persist the data in these fields via the textFieldDidEndEditing method. How can I distinguish between the two fields in the method?

My current code is as follows:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    let touchPosition:CGPoint = textField.convert(CGPoint.zero, to:self.storiesTableView)

    let indexPath = self.storiesTableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPosition)

    let storyForEdit = self.stories?[indexPath!.row]

    var editedTitleText = ""

    let cell = tableView(storiesTableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath!) as! StoryCell

    let storyTitleField = cell.storyTitleField


    if textField.text?.isEmpty ?? true {

        deleteTitle(at: storyForEdit!)

    } else {

        editedTitleText = textField.text ?? ""

        do {
            try self.realm.write {
                storyForEdit!.title = editedTitleText
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error editing story \(error)")
        }

        self.storiesTableView.reloadData()


    }
}
```

I have reference outlets to the two fields in the storyCell.swift:

```
class StoryCell: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var storyTitleField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var authorField: UITextField!

....}
```

However, when I try to distinguish between the two fields with code such as (suggested here: [iphone: uitextfield, multiple textfields with the same delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747315/iphone-uitextfield-multiple-textfields-with-the-same-delegate)):

```
    if textField == storyTitleField {

        print("Here we are in storyTitle field")

    }
```

Nothing happens - no data is persisted. But if I just use the generic textField then I cannot differentiate between the title and author textFields. Thanks for any suggestions on this.

Comment: Use the component's `tag` property?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've seen this suggested in other posts and will give it a try, however, I thought as the reference outlets already exist for the fields that the outlets would be the way to go?

Comment: Are the outlets within the same context as the delegate?  If so, you can simply compare `textField` to the outlets.  If the delegate is declared in some other context, then using `tag` is probably a (slightly) better solution

Comment: The outlets are in the storyCell.swift. The DidEndEditing is in the viewcontroller.

Comment: Then comparing the outlets with the reference isn't going to work.  You could have multiple instances of the cell in the table view and it would be very difficult to determine which cell was been edited. In the long run, using `tag` is much simpler and less error prone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a different tag for each TextField (

```swift
txtFld1.tag = 5
txtFld2.tag = 6
```

) and then in the textFieldDidEndEditing check the tag of the textField.

Answer (score 3):

you can try this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textfield1.delegate = self
        textfield1.tag = 11

        textfield2.delegate = self
        textfield2.tag = 22

        textfield3.delegate = self
        textfield3.tag = 33
}



func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        if textField.tag == 11
        {
            //your code here
        }

        if textField.tag == 22
        {
            //your code here
        }

        if textField.tag == 33
        {
            //your code here
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Khushai. This is the way I went in the end although I set up the tags in the storyCell.swift file with the following:                       
                                                                                 
    func setStory(storyRealm : Story) {
        
        story = storyRealm
        
        storyTitleField.tag = 5
        
        authorField.tag = 6                  }